# get result of overpass api by osmbonuspack

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, overpass-api

Hi i every one i have used osmbonuspack(for android) for making feature of searching POI, this api offer option to post request to overpass api,i want to get this result in format json.Thank you for advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the result in JSON then just query [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) directly and request JSON as [output format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Output_Format_.28out.29). osmbonuspack has support for Overpass API via [OverpassAPIProvider](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/OverpassAPIProvider) but is targeted at converting the results to markers.

Comment: yes this my issue ,i want to access direct to number phone and email for doing some traitement so i need to get the result in json format without converting it to kml.

Comment: So what's wrong with accessing Overpass API directly?

Comment: i want to exploit the result ,so i should access to every information for example phone of POI for sending sms...,if i can get result in json format ,i can easly do that

Comment: Yes, I got that already from your original question. Access Overpass API directly via HTTP.

Comment: yes,i well try to do that without using api osmbonuspack thank you very much

Comment: Please don't forget to set a meaningful User Agent in your HTTP header and also take a look at the usage policy wrt number of requests per day for your app.